# PostgreSQL 上のバイナリデータを一括でローカルに保存したい

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 上のバイナリデータを一括ローカル保存したい。
※できればDbeaver 上で操作して

Dbeaverでなくても良いのですが、日常的に発生する業務なので、
何らかのツールでできればと思っています。

WEBサービスの管理者を任されまして、
音声データがバイナリデータとしてPostgreSQLの中に格納されているのですが、
これを必要な分保存したく思っています。
※保存して中身を聞く必要があります。

一件ずつ保存する方法はあるのですが、何百とありますので、
一件ずつ手作業で保存するのは不可能です。

どなたか、詳しい方教えていただければ幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお、他サイトとマルチポストしております。
https://qiita.com/yokumura/questions/a7f812dff276187f36ee

Qiitaとこちらだけ残し、あとは削除依頼中です。

Answer (score 2):

DbeaverでエクスポートしたいBLOBを選択して、
「結果セットのエクスポート」を行います。
例としてCSVで出力すると、設定画面が出てきますので、バイナリの設定でファイルに保存を選択して保存すると、CSV出力先のフォルダに[files]フォルダができて、
中にバイナリファイルがすべて格納されています。

蛇足ですが、あとはそれをcmdで一括リネームすればOKでした。

[image: 68d4dbbb5c8424d9e16f1baac5141571.png]
[image: 0ae45cd3a6ee83d654850ecf26a045ca.png]